# Is it possible in Angular reactive forms to validate on conditions out of the form?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on Angular reactive forms validation. I have an input with google autocomplete implemented on it:

```
<input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="input-auto input" formControlName="address">
```

It is standard implementation, everytime you enter some keyword, you get places suggestions:

[image: google-autocomplete]

Now, what I would like to do is to validate the address. **The address needs to contain zip code - only then should be valid**. So once you type something and choose one of the suggestions, the validation should be fired. When chosen suggestion contains zip code is valid, when not - is invalid.

As you can see there is only one form control for the whole address (and this should stay like that), which I fill with formatted address from google API. I'm getting also the information about the address components from google places API, which I store in global variables (`zipCode`, `countryName`, `cityName`, `streetName`):

```
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const autocomplete = new window['google'].maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementToRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ['address']
      });
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {

          const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          this.form.get('address').setValue(place.formatted_address);

          for (const addressComponent of place.address_components) {
            for (const addressComponentType of addressComponent.types) {
              switch (addressComponentType) {
                case 'postal_code':
                  this.zipCode = addressComponent.long_name;
                  break;
                case 'country':
                  this.countryName = addressComponent.long_name;
                  break;
                case 'locality':
                  this.cityName = addressComponent.long_name;
                  break;
                case 'route':
                  this.streetName = addressComponent.long_name;
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

In the method which creates the form with `FormBuilder` I use custom validator:

```
  public createFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      address: [null, this.zipCodeValidator()]
    });
  }
```

With below custom validation method I would like to get the error when the `zipCode` is missing in address:

```
  public zipCodeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: boolean } | null> => {
      if (this.zipCode !== undefined) {
        return of({ zipCode: true });
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

However the form it is not correctly validated, because no matter I get the address with or without zip code - it is always valid:

[image: form print]

If I use as a condition form control related value, the validation it's working. So updating the validation method to the below state generates an error when there is nothing entered to the input:

```
  public zipCodeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: boolean } | null> => {
      if (control.value === null) {
        return of({ noValue: true });
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to validate the form like that - with the conditions actually out of the form (since I do not pass this `zipCode` value to any form control directly)?

Comment: TDLR; When you have reactive form, what you actually have, is data model. You can do whatever you want/need with that data model. So ye, its possible to validate on whatever conditions needed.

Comment: @Antoniossss great, but why it doesn't work then? What am I missing?

Comment: In your validator you are checking for `this.zipCode`, but you need to check the `control.value` for the zipcode.

Comment: @MitchMcCutchen this is actually the question I've asked, I know that I should but do I need?

Comment: If you look at the image you posted from the console, those properties are the properties you have access to in the controls. You can pass a parameter to the validator  `public zipCodeValidator(zipCode): ValidatorFn {` and check that. You would need to pass it that zipCode property you have set in the component.

Comment: Thanks @MitchMcCutchen for your tip, I've got this almost working even without passing it like you've mentioned, but now have problems with proper triggering the validation - updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, **it is possible to validate on conditions out of the form** and as usually it was very close to me.

First I've messed up with the validation method. `Observable` I've used is for [async-validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation). So after fixing it, the method will return the object only, not the Observable:

```
  public zipCodeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (control.value !== null) {
        // if value exists, we can add number of conditions
        if (this.zipCode !== undefined) {
          return { zipCode: true };
        }
      } else {
          // here we can react when there is no value entered - act as validator.required
          return { empty: true}
        }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

Then I've started to get the validation done, but for the previous state of the `zipCode` variable. I thought because maybe I need to use the async-validation, but it was even simpler. I've set the value of address form control too early:   `this.form.get('address').setValue(place.formatted_address);`
So I've moved it behind the part where I'm looking for the zip code and it worked:

```
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
  const autocomplete = new window['google'].maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementToRef.nativeElement, {
    types: ['address']
  });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {

      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
        return;
      }

      for (const addressComponent of place.address_components) {
        for (const addressComponentType of addressComponent.types) {
          switch (addressComponentType) {
            case 'postal_code':
              this.zipCode = addressComponent.long_name;
              break;
            case 'country':
              this.countryName = addressComponent.long_name;
              break;
            case 'locality':
              this.cityName = addressComponent.long_name;
              break;
            case 'route':
              this.streetName = addressComponent.long_name;
              break;
          }
        }
      }

      this.form.get('address').setValue(place.formatted_address);
    });
  });
});
```

There is also question about what if I want to fire the validation in other moment, not from beginning. Then just need to set it in the right place and update the validators:

```
this.form.get('address').setValidators(this.zipCodeValidator());
this.form.get('address').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Also if there is a need to remove it at some point, here is the easy way:

```
this.form.get('address').clearValidators();
```